# Determine $A ∩ B ∩ D, (A \setminus D) ∩ B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am just starting a discrete math course at university and this is the first question on my first assignment. Sorry you will think it is extremely simple. Funny part is I can do most of the questions after this one.

Let $A = \{n  \in \mathbb{N} : n \ \text{is odd} \ \}$,

$B = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : 0 \le x < 100\}$,

$C = ℚ$, $D = \{3^n : n ∈ ℕ\}$

and $ℝ$ be the universal set.

Determine $A ∩ B ∩ D, (A \setminus D) ∩ B$

What I think:

$$A ∩ B ∩ D = \{x, n \mid x ∈ ℕ\text{ is odd and }3^n \mid n ∈ ℕ\}$$

$(A \setminus D) \cap B = {}$no idea

Comment: Be aware which definition of natural numbers is being used. If $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ then powers of $3$ are $\{1,3,9,27,\ldots\}$, but if $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ then the powers of $3$ are $\{3,9,27,\ldots\}$.

Comment: @FlyByNight : You used \backslash where you should have used \setminus. Notice the difference: $A\backslash D$ versus $A\setminus D$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Hi @MichaelHardy, I didn't even know that \setminus was a "command". Thanks for point that out; I'll change it now.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Oh, I see you already changed it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in words:

The set $A \cap B \cap D$ is the set of "all elements of $\mathbb{R}$ that are odd natural numbers (in $A$), no less than 0 and strictly less than 100 (in $B$), and are natural powers of 3 (in $D$)".

First off, the only natural powers of 3 (elements of $D$) that are "no less than 0 and strictly less than 100" (in $B$) are _____.

Among these, _____ are odd natural numbers (in $A$), so we quickly see that

$$A \cap B \cap D = %\{1,3,9,27,81\}$$

(P.S. if a set is small, say 5 or fewer elements, then it is usually best just to list the elements explicitly).

For $(A \backslash D) \cap B$, we have "all elements of $\mathbb{R}$ that are odd natural numbers that are **not** natural powers of 3 (in $A \backslash D$), and are no less than 0 and strictly less than 100 (in $B$)".

Thus we have $(A \backslash D) \cap B = %\{1,2,5,7,11,\ldots,25,29,\ldots,79,83,\ldots,99\} = \{2n+1:0 \leq n \leq 49\}\backslash\{3,9,27,81\}$

Comment: Thank you for your very clear explanation. Wording it like that makes it seem very simple and easy to understand!

Comment: 0 is not a power of 3.

Comment: @Marconius yes I realized that quite quickly after posting thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't get confused by the use of different pronumerals to mark what's in each set. In words, the sets are:

A: "The set of odd natural numbers"

B: "The set of real numbers between zero (inclusive) and 100 (exclusive)"

C: "The set of rational numbers"

D: "The set of powers of three"

So to write, for example, $A \cap B \cap D$, you want the set of all numbers that are (a) odd natural numbers *and* (b) real numbers from zero to 100 *and* (c) powers of three. Whereas for $(A \backslash D) \cap B$ you want all numbers that are odd natural numbers that are *not* powers of three, but that *are* between zero and 100. Can you write either of those in set notation?

Answer (score 1):

> Let
>
> - $A = \{x \mid x \in\Bbb N\text{ is odd}\} =\{x\in \Bbb N\mid \exists k\in\Bbb N: x=2k+1\}$,
> - $B = \{a \in\Bbb R \mid 0 \leq a < 100\}$,
> - $C = \Bbb Q$,
> - $D = \{3^n \mid n \in\Bbb N\} = \{x\in \Bbb N\mid \exists n\in\Bbb N: x= 3^n\} $
> - and $\Bbb R$ be the universal set.
>
> Determine $A ∩ B ∩ D$,

Intersection means all set constructions must be satisfied.

The intersection between :odd integers, reals between $[0;100)$, and integer powers of 3 will be... integer powers of 3 that are odd and between $1$ and $81$ (inclusive).

In fact: $\{1,3,9,81\}$  Just those.

> (A \ D) ∩ B

Set difference means the set construction of the divided set must not be satisfied.

Which means we have integers in the interval of $\{0..99\}$ that are odd but *not* integer powers of three.